# .net MVC: resolve a view related to a type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm trying to render a Model in MVC that takes a list of Content objects `List<Content>()`

A `Content` is a base class and can be one of many different derived types eg: (TextBox, Schedule etc...)

In my View, while iterating through the list of contents **I want to address a view that matches the type of the Content's derived class**. (so that TextBox uses it's own view, Schedule it's own view and so on...)

How can I achieve this? Maybe I need to do some binding in the ViewModel?

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Comment: You need to create `Editor Templates` and then use `Html.EditorFor` with the model. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it :)

Comment: See my answer, very simple, yet it can help you.

Comment: @ramiramilu a simple Model for TextContent:

`namespace myc.Models
{
    public class TextContent: Content
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}`

The base class:

`namespace myc.Models
{
    public class Content
    {
        public int Weight { get; set; }
    }
}`

And I would just like to render something like so:

`@foreach (var Content in Model.Page.Contents)
{
    <p>@Content -> myTextContentHere</p>
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your model -

```
public class Content
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}

public class TextContent : Content
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a controller action -

```
    public ActionResult GetContents()
    {
        var contents = new List<TextContent>()
        {
            new TextContent() {Text = "Sample Text"},
            new TextContent() {Text = "Second Sample Content"}
        };

        return View(contents);
    }
```

now create a folder called `EditorTemplates` in `Shared` folder of `Views` folder and place following cshtml with name `TextContent.cshtml` (Note: name of the cshtml file should be matching with the model name, otherwise custom editor template will not be rendered).

```
@model myc.Models.TextContent

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
```

Now create your view with `IEnumerable<myc.Models.TextContent>` -

```
model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Controllers.TextContent>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetContents";
}

<h2>GetContents</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item)
}
```

When you run the application and go to the view, you will get -

[image]

Comment: How/Where exactly was your `GetContents` method called? I can't find it. Secondly, The `model` you put is `IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Controllers.TextContent`, but @Mikou needs to iterate generic base class objects list, of type `Content`. You specified the `TextContent` instead of its base class...

Comment: `GetContents` is a `Action` method, it is a `GET` call, just any any other get call for a page. Well for `IEnumerable<Content>`, once can alsways change that. Basically have you tried my solution with `Content` type?

Comment: I know that's an action method. But you showed a example of the view which was suppose to call this action method, and even showed the result which is the page with two input boxes. So I was wondering if your example is missing the part where you need to call the action method?

Comment: I think you are little confused, `GrtContents action method will result in the view which i described`, it is not reverse. And when it comes to textboxes, it is just an example to show how editor templates works.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate your list, and on each iteration call a partial view which matches the iterated object type (what you called "Content").

You can encapsulate a public property in you content class, to hold the view name. Or you can also use the object's method `GetType` instead.

Something like this (where your list of objects resides in Model.ContentList):

```
foreach (var _content in Model.ContentList) {
   @Html.Partial(_content.ViewName, _content); // the "ViewName" would hold different names, such as: "TextBox", "Schedule" from your question.
}
```

Comment: I see. However, it's not super nice with the additional public field to store the viewName. But I guess it can quickly fix my problem for now.

Comment: You can also use the object's `GetType()` method. If you use it, you can avoid the need of adding a new field..

Comment: Did this help you? what did you eventually use?

Comment: Sorry I went off for lunch. I choose ramiramilu solution. With your solution I also had to make a cast in order for it to work:

@Html.Partial((String) Content.GetType().Name, (myc.Models.TextContent) Content);